# How aircraft move? Or moves?

Tags: past-tense, grammaticality-in-context, singular

I saw a book titled

> "How Aircraft Move Through the Air".

But is that correct? I think aircraft is the singular. So
Would it be "moves" or "moved"(in case of past sentence)?

Am I wrong? 
Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Aircraft is both singular and plural. Like sheep.

If it is used in a way that could be singular or plural, the singular is denoted by use of an article.

> "How aircraft move through the air"

Plural.

> "How an aircraft moves through the air"

Singular.

A definite article can be applied to the singular or plural (the plural potentially acting more like a mass noun).

> "How the aircraft moves through the air"
>
> "How the aircraft move through the air"

Both are valid, but with different meaning.